# How to get textbox data (txtusername.text) data from the windows form 1(frmlogin) to form 2(frmmain) SQL query

Tags: c#

I facing error when want to pass my data which insert at Form1(frmLogin) to Form2(frmMain) SQL Query.

Form1(frmLogin)coding

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SytelineAutoGenerateDocNum
{
    public partial class frmLogin : Form
    {
        public frmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=P13L3CFN756\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Syteline_Misc_DocNum;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234;");
            string query = "SELECT *FROM [Syteline_Misc_DocNum].[dbo].[users] Where username = '" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "' and password = '" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dtbl);


            if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                frmMain objFrmMain = new frmMain();
                
                //objFrmMain.Value = txtUsername.Text;
               //objFrmMain.ShowDialog();
                objFrmMain.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Check your username and password");
            }
            
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Form2(frmMain)Coding

```
private void buttonGDN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       con.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into DocNum (Date,UserID,BusinessUnit,RunningNumber,DocumentNumber)values('" + txtUsername.Text + "')");
   }
```

My Error is (The Name "txtUsername" does not exist in the current context).
I have provided an image of the error I am getting [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcpzN.png)

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks

What I have tried:

I have no idea on the Error.
I have tried to enable the System Configuration on the reference, this did not solve the issue.

Comment: Drop everything you're doing and go learn about SQL Injection and how to prevent them using parameterized queries.

Comment: it seems that txtUsername is in the other form. can u provide the whole code of the both forms?

Comment: You have more than one form.  So you need to reference controls on second form using an instance of the form.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net